# Setting up google Adsense on a mediaTemples account

Tags: dns, mediatemple, nameservers

I am setting up Ad-sense on my website and the instructions tell me that i should set my nameservers to point to ns1.googleghs.com. I know how to set my nameservers, and right now they point to ns1.mediatemple.net.

If I change where they point how is it going to find my website?

or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mix up "AdSense for content" with "AdSense for domains".
 ( http://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/topic.py?topic=8433 )

If you just want to show some ads on your website (by including html-code into your page), then you don't have to change any dns entries. ("AdSense for content")

You only need this if you want to "park" your domain for example. And let Google generate the content. ( http://www.google.com/domainpark/ )

Comment: i totally did mix those two up, thanks for the clarification. When i was setting up my AdSense account I must have enabled 'for domains' along with 'for content' without realizing exactly what it was. thanks again.